# Problema com validação 'unique' em Laravel

Tags: laravel

Olá, estou começando a aprender Laravel, estou fazendo um pequeno projeto e estou na parte de validações, porém estou tendo problemas com a validação quando quero validar um valor único (unique).

```
class Categoria extends Model {

public $timestamps = false;

public function frases() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Frase');
}

public function validar($request) {
    $mensagens = [
        'nome.required' => 'O campo nome é obrigatório!',
        'nome.max' => 'O limite de caracteres do campo nome foi excedido!',
        'descricao.required' => 'O campo descricao é obrigatório!',
        'descricao.max' => 'O limite de caracteres do campo descricao foi excedido!',
        'tipo.required' => 'O campo tipo é obrigatório!',
        'slug.required' => 'O campo slug é obrigatório!',
        'slug.max' => 'O limite de caracteres do campo slug foi excedido!',
        'slug.unique' => 'O slug ja existe',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nome' => 'required|max:40',
        'descricao' => 'required|max:150',
        'tipo' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|max:40|unique:categorias',
    ], $mensagens);

    return $validator;}
}
```

Bom, como dá para ver a validação de fato funciona, mas quando vou editar uma categoria ela acaba dizendo que o valor do slug já existe, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma para criar uma exceção se for o dono do slug que está sendo editado...

Obrigado por enquanto :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, vou deixar para aqueles que estão enfrentando o mesmo problema. Na parte da validação eu inclui a indicação de id do cadastro a ser modificado, desta forma ele entende que o unique não se aplica a esse cadastro, já que ele é o dono do mesmo...

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nome' => 'required|max:40',
        'descricao' => 'required|max:150',
        'tipo' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|max:40|unique:categorias,slug,'.$request->id //essa linha
    ], $mensagens);
```